# Want to compare two dates and take out the difference in days

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting Timestamp from Firebase Firestore and then formatting it into date and then want to take out the difference in days. And for that I am doing this:-

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.parse(nameTimestamp!=null? nameTimestamp.toDate().toString() :DateTime.now().toString());
    print('$myDateTime');
    String formattedDateTime = DateFormat('yyyy,MM,dd').format(myDateTime);
    print('$formattedDateTime');

    final nameChangeDate = DateTime(2021,6,1);
    final todayDate = DateTime.now();
    final difference = todayDate.difference(nameChangeDate).inDays;
    print(difference);
```

And now the problem I am facing is if I put  formattedDateTime in front of nameChangeDate  like mentioned below then at difference there's appear an error that *The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'*.

```
final nameChangeDate = formattedDateTime;
    final todayDate = DateTime.now();
    final difference = todayDate.difference(nameChangeDate).inDays;  ///Error 
    print(difference);
```

Help me in this or guide me to take out the difference in some other way.

Comment: The `difference()` method accepts **DateTime object** as parameter. 
`external Duration difference(DateTime other);`
In your case nameChangeDate is declared as String.

Try this:
`final difference = todayDate.difference(DateTime.parse(nameChangeDate)).inDays;` I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: It's done. thanks.

Comment: You start with a `DateTime`, format it as a `String`, and then try to compute the time difference.  That doesn't make sense; just compute the time difference directly using the original `DateTime` instead of formatting it and then parsing it back.

Comment: Also beware that some days are 23 or 25 hours, but a localtime date difference from midnight of one day to midnight of the next using .inDays might show 0 because it truncates the 23 hour day to shorter than 1 day.